# WebGL in Chrome works second time but not first time

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

WebGL does not work in the following three scenarios:

(for the 'test webgl' site used get.webgl.org)

1  Start chrome, Google search for the 'test webgl' site, click on the link in the search result.

2 Go to the 'test webgl' site from a link in an email.

3 Start Chrome from a short cut or command prompt, "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://get.webgl.org/

This only happens when Chrome is not already running.  In other words WebGL does not work when chrome starts up.  However it does work if chrome is already running.

The best demonstration is scenario number 3, above. This starts chrome and goes to http://get.webgl.org/ and Webgl does not work. Then do exactly the same again but this time with chrome already open and Webgl works.

Would very much appreciate feedback or a solution, thanks.

Have also created various test sites in html, javascript and webgl, in order to find a work-around. For example if webgl is not available then allow the user to click on a link to open the page in a new tab, this does not work. However if the user opens a new tab then loads the page, webgl is detected and works.

In short, if a customer opens chrome and searches for your website (that has webgl content). Then clicks on the link, webgl will not work.  It does not seem reasonable to then instruct the customer to open a new tab and then go to the same website a second time. So far have not been able to find a solution so that it just works without the customer having to fiddle around.

I realize that this may be a chrome issue as it does not occur in firefox, however am trying to find a javascript solution rather than waiting for chrome developers to fix it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

(Windows XP Pro, Chrome V36)

Hi Mack,

Thanks for your reply. The majority of visitors to my web site have XP and Chrome.  I should imagine that this is true for quite a lot of peoples, websites.

**Problem 1**  The first fallback I had on my website was to detect if webgl is supported. If yes then continue as normal. If no then display a help page. This was simple and worked, however, google crawlers do not handle the javascript very well, therefore always index the webgl help page, rather than the home page.

**Solution 1**  Managed to fix this by having a popup box appear when webgl is not supported, giving the user a choice of whether to continue or go to the help page. The conditional code that processes the user response is arranged so that if the user is a google crawler then it simply 'falls through' and displays the html content of the home page, and not the help page.

There are lots of web sites that seem to have this same problem, including get.webgl.org, in other words, if you do a google search for a website, and that site contains webgl detection and fallback code, the search result always shows the fallback content, rather than the authors intended main content.

**Problem 2** Now that I finally have the home page listed correctly by google, found that am still losing many customers, as they are starting chrome, searching google for my site 'suit yourself shirts', clicking the link in the result and being told incorrectly that webgl is not supported.

Am very interested in your solution but do not quite understand how it works. Have tried detection then page refresh or load the page in a new tab or display a link for the user to load the page, but none of these methods seem to work. Seems like quite a fundamental problem that would effect many webgl websites. Would be very greatfull if you could explain your suggestion a little further.  Thanks for your help, kind regards - Gary

Comment: Does not happen to me at all, using Windows 7/Chrome 36. The only workaround I can suggest you is to create and detect a javascript cookie expiring on browser session. If the cookie isn't set you can refresh automatically the page, and then finally setting the cookie once WebGL starts.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mack, please see amended post above.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. Yeah, page refresh was the correct idea, so you did understood correctly. Still quite odd, your site is working fine as well other webgl sites with Chrome opened fresh. Tried also that on a Mac OS X and does not happen. I starting to think that's the Windows XP fault rather than a code/browser problem. Did you tried on another Windows XP machine?

Comment: Hi Mack, Thanks for your help and for taking the time to try it on various sites.  Think you are correct that it seems to only occur with Window XP.  Tried it on another machine with Windows 7 and there was no problem.  Am stumped as to how to fix it with javascript, WebGL, etc. Kind regards, Gary